# Which MariaDB-Galera Node Should I Start After Cluster Crushing or Failing?

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, ubuntu, galera

Sometimes my 3-Node GaleraCluster fails and doesn't serve. When I check I see all of them are activated but two of them are not working, so I check log files I see one of them could not operate an query and doesn't serves anymore.

I kill all nodes proccesses with:

```
sudo ps -aux | grep mysql
sudo kill -9 proccessID
```

After then I check the /var/lib/mysql/grastate.dat file and which has the higher seqno, I start it with "galera_new_cluster" command, after then I start other nodes and some replication operations are being processing for 20-30minute. Is it right to start the cluster like that? Which node should I start firstly, because sometimes the node with higher seqno doesn't start properly, it doesn't work to make safe_to_bootstrap parameter 1.

What is the right operation in this situation? What are you doing when your cluster breaks down? I don't want to loss any data,

Comment: see [crash recovery](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/crash-recovery.html)

Comment: @danblack I followed the instructions in the link you have gave but when I use the option "mysqld --wsrep-recover" and started the cluster according to the instructions, I saw that the data loss occurred. How can I be sure the data will not loss?

Comment: if you have innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit at any value other than `1` that makes the assumption that they don't all fail at once and hence a total failure will loose data. Its hard to know without details as to which recovery mechanism was chosen and why other loss may have occurred.

Comment: @danblack the cluster was crushed and I could nof find which node was the most updated, all safe_to_bootstrap parameters was -1 and I tried to start the cluster from the biggest seq_no parameter node (Node 3), but the cluster could not be built. I used mysqld --wsrep-recover option to find the most updated node and I saw the node was Node 2. I started the cluster from Node 2 and everything went right, the cluster was built. When I check the last commits which were done by clients to create some tables which were used for 3 hours by clients I saw none of them was in the db this was the data los